# Access denied when starting SQL Server Express from command line

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

Windows 7 computer running SQL Server Express 2008 (sp1).

When I try to run **net start mssql$sqlexpress** I receive an error:

> *System error 5 has occurred.*
>   *Access is denied*

The SQL service is running under "Network Service" account

The service starts fine if I use the services window. Could somebody help me figure out why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 3):

Did you start the console in Administrator mode ?

Comment: Not explicitly, I am an administrator, why would I need to?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are logged on to Administator account or that your account is in Administators group. In Vista/Seven this is different than in xp. If you want to allow some application to do Administator stuff, you have to explicitly start it with administator privileges.

Comment: I just ran into this problem on win7 and can confirm running as Administrator is the fix.  Received the same error as Brettski.  Opened a command prompt "As Administrator", ran "net start mssql$sqlexpress", and sql server started just fine.